# Can I delete files from C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\PeerDistRepub\Store\0?

Tags: windows, storage, windirstat

```
C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\PeerDistRepub\Store\0
```

This directory contains many, many .dat files which use ~33% of my 500GB disk space. I found this using WinDirStat.

The question in [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/166272/is-it-safe-to-delete-files-in-c-windows-serviceprofiles-localservice-appdata-lo) is similar, but refers to files in \Local\Temp.

Is it safe to delete these files? What are they for?

Comment: Yes but use command prompt "netsh branchcache flush" to delete them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be an answer, not a comment:

> Yes but use command prompt "netsh branchcache flush" to delete them. –
> Moab

Ran the command on my system and the c:\windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService directory shrank to 57.7MB.

Comment: To whomever: It is good etiquette when downvoting an answer to leave a comment indicating why so that the poster can learn from the situation.

Comment: I didn't vote, but it's probably because you didn't explain it or link to a reputable source that explains it, whereas a good SU answer entails that both are done.

Comment: Votes are for how useful an answer is, not how complete its pedigree is.

Comment: This command results in this error message "This command can only be executed when BranchCache is installed". (Windows Server 2019)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can delete files in this folder. See these threads.

[Delete system service profiles](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/3795364f-b66c-43ae-82d3-8ed5eb1aa2ce/local-service-system-profile-grown-to-extremely-large-size?forum=winserverTS)

This is a cache file for font, you can safely delete it.

This is one example.

[Delete system service profiles 2](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/8x4vp8/windows_delivery_optimization_using_730_gb_on_os_c/)

1. Use disk clean up (build in windows) and see if it can remove it, i am almost sure it will, just click to clean up system files too at the bottom of window
2. There is a Delivery Optimization in settings used to share windows update files with other pc's. See if you have that turned on.
3. You must be on some older version of Windows 10 and Windows Update decided that it is time to move on and upgrade you to the latest version. It shouldn't take this much space.

============

a. Make sure Windows is up to date.

b. Then run Disk Cleanup and use the option to clean up system files. Select all items for cleanup.

c. Restart when done and then if the folder is still large you can delete files in it.

The research I have done suggests using Disk Cleanup. I also quote from a comment here (Friend Moab): netsh branchcache flush"

My folders (two computers here) are essentially empty (< 5 MB) and I keep Windows up to date and use Disk Cleaner (including System Files) weekly.